# SPSS loop linear regression with different variables

Tags: python, spss

I have a dataset which consists of a list of companies and 1 value per company. I have arranged the data so every column is a different company and thus a different variable. Each variable then contains 1 value.

I now need to loop a linear regression and save the r squared of all possible regressions.

For example (with A, B and C being companies):

> A = b0 + b1 * B
>
> A = b0 + b1 * C
>
> B = b0 + b1 * C

I have limited experience with SPSS and no experience with coding in Python, so I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Wait, you have a single data point for each company?

Comment: Yes, one per year, but my professor wants me to analyse each year separately.

Comment: I can think of some things to use, but it's important to know a little more of your data and your experience in SPSS. What have you tried so far? How far have you come? What do the data look like? And what is the unit of analysis? I mean: what's in the rows of your data? Not these companies, are they?